# Inserting data with SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

Similar questions have already appeard here, but it seems like I'm doing the same as in other instructions, but it doesn't work.  So I have

```
Declare @Counter Int

Set @Counter = 1

while @Counter <= 1000

Begin
    insert into Kiso_task_table ([Numbers],[Square_root])
     values ( @Counter, Sqrt(@Counter));
     Set @Counter = @Counter + 1;
     CONTINUE;
End 

SELECT TOP (1000) [Numbers],[Square_root]
  FROM [Kiso_task].[dbo].[Kiso_task_table]
```

and it should give me Numbers from 1 to 1000 and their square roots, respectively - instead it produces "1" all the times? Do you know what is wrong?

Comment: This does not look like MySQL at all.

Comment: Top is not mysql are you trying to convert to mysql or is this incorreclty tagged?

Comment: SQRT() returns a float. Is Square_root defined as a float in the table?

Comment: No, I have
 Numbers varchar(1000), Square_root varchar(1000)

Comment: Silly question, but is your table empty at the start of this, or is TOP (1000) returning rows that previously existed?

Comment: You should not be storing your numbers as a `VARCHAR`...it sounds like your `Numbers` attribute should be of type `INT`, and your `Square_root` attribute should be of type `DECIMAL`.

Comment: My table is empty at the begining

Comment: query is working for me in `SQL SERVER`. What's your output?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using though. SQL Server, Mysql, Oracle, Postgres, something else? This is going to be very RDBMS specific.

Comment: Another silly question, but you prefix your Select table with the DB Name, but not your Insert - are you running this in the same DB so that your Insert is using the same table?

Comment: @BlueGI suspected that too.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me on MSSQL. Could you confirm the RDBMS you're using (MSSQL, MySQL, Oracle, Postgres, etc.) and perhaps provide the DDL statement for your table and some example data so we can reproduce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is in the type of variable to convert the square root, it must be of the 'float' type

```
CREATE TABLE #Kiso_task_table
(
    [Numbers] INT,
    [Square_root] FLOAT,

);
GO

DECLARE @Counter INT

SET @Counter = 1

WHILE @Counter <= 1000
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO #Kiso_task_table ([Numbers],[Square_root]) VALUES ( @Counter, Sqrt(@Counter));
    SET @Counter = @Counter + 1
    CONTINUE
END 

SELECT TOP (1000) [Numbers],[Square_root]
FROM #Kiso_task_table
```

[SQRT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sqrt-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: As long as @Counter is an INT (as it was in the OP), then the destination field can be VARCHAR (although that's just plain wrong) due to implicit conversions.  The original code works as-is whether it's FLOAT, INT or VARCHAR but it just doesn't give the necessary precision.

Comment: If precision is sought, the output data must be of a decimal or numeric type, but originally the function of a float. If we take it to a whole type or varchar it will approach.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is *procedural thinking*. Try to start thinking *set-based*. That means: No `CURSOR`, no `WHILE`, no loopings, no *do this and then this and finally this*. Let the engine know, what you want to get back and let the engine decide how to do this.

```
DECLARE @mockupTarget TABLE(Number INT, Square_root DECIMAL(12,8));

WITH TallyOnTheFly(Number) AS
(
    SELECT TOP 1000 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM master..spt_values
)
INSERT INTO @mockupTarget(Number,Square_root)
SELECT Number,SQRT(Number)
FROM TallyOnTheFly;

SELECT * FROM @mockupTarget ORDER BY Number;
```

The tally-cte will create a volatile set of 1000 numbers. This is inserted in one single statement.

### Btw

I tested your code against my *mockup* table and it was working just fine...

Comment: Thank you for your anwser. So far it's too advanced for me, but I'm gratefull for showing me the path. I'll try to follow.